# i want to know that is it possible to call biopython library in jython?

Tags: jython

I am using netbeans 8.2 with python plugin 8.1. I want to code in jython with using biopython library.
Kindly tell me whether it's possible or not if so than how ?

Comment: You can try that on your own first... or lookup online resources for that

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, Biopython libraries are libraries written for Python (and so, in C, C++ or FORTRAN).

You ***cannot*** run them directly from Jython because Jython is "Python for Java" - a project where Python language was re-implemented. Jython Documentation mentions:

> Unlike the CPython distribution, Jython does not include built-in libraries written in C as they will not work on the Java platform. Instead, there are certain libraries that have been re-written in the Java languages to be included with Jython

But if you also have a Python interpreter installed on your machine, you could run your Python interpreter via commandline. You could also think about invoking Python interpreter via Java exec command from your Jython project, and collect the result, to provide it in a way that you can continue in Jython after fetching the result from Python.

Comment: Thank you so much but if you kindly please elaborate how to invoke python interpreter from java. I am new to programming so i couldn't understand it.